# Insufficient privilege error while creating Activities record

Tags: permissions, activities

In my enterprise org. I am trying to create Activities record.While creating the record I am getting

> In sufficient Privelage error.

Private sharing is there for Activities record. But I am not able to create task record even for my owned record. Also I have 'modify all' access for the object for which I am creating the task.

Edit Task and Edit Event are also true for my profile.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: In your org, are you using the standard create activities page, or is it by chance a VF page?

Comment: What happens when you try with Apex? `Task t = new Task(Subject = 'Test');
insert t;
System.debug(t.Id);`

Comment: I am using standard task button for creating new task

Comment: Try checking "Field Level Accessibility" for the fields & record-type (if any) for which your profile has permission's to access and to which you do not have access still you are accessing it. Might be this helps you.  

Chirag